# Empty shared lib for command 'oozie admin sharedliblist ...'

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I have installed oozie and also installed the shared lib as per the instruction here

http://mockus.in/forum/viewtopic.php?t=48

When I ran the example MapReduce Workflow accompanying the installation, the workflow failed. In the webconsole log, I could see this error message

```
2015-05-24 18:09:32,664  WARN ActionStartXCommand:544 - 
SERVER[mountain] USER[mountain] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[map-reduce-wf] 
JOB[0000000-150524175852032-oozie-moun-W] ACTION[0000000-150524175852032-
oozie-moun-W@mr-node] Error starting action [mr-node]. ErrorType [FAILED], 
ErrorCode [It should never happen], Message [File /user/mountain/share/lib 
does not exist]
```

I could see the shared lib is available in my hdfs

```
mountain@mountain:~/oo/conf$ hdfs dfs -ls share/lib/*
drwxr-xr-x   - mountain supergroup          0 2015-05-24 21:47 share/lib/lib_20150524214701/distcp
drwxr-xr-x   - mountain supergroup          0 2015-05-24 21:47 share/lib/lib_20150524214701/hcatalog
drwxr-xr-x   - mountain supergroup          0 2015-05-24 21:47 share/lib/lib_20150524214701/hive
drwxr-xr-x   - mountain supergroup          0 2015-05-24 21:47 share/lib/lib_20150524214701/mapreduce-streaming
drwxr-xr-x   - mountain supergroup          0 2015-05-24 21:47 share/lib/lib_20150524214701/oozie
drwxr-xr-x   - mountain supergroup          0 2015-05-24 21:47 share/lib/lib_20150524214701/pig
-rw-r--r--   3 mountain supergroup       1348 2015-05-24 21:47 share/lib/lib_20150524214701/sharelib.properties
drwxr-xr-x   - mountain supergroup          0 2015-05-24 21:47 share/lib/lib_20150524214701/sqoop
```

The command to list the shared library also returned empty

```
mountain@mountain:~/oo/conf$ oozie admin -shareliblist -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie
[Available ShareLib]
```

Am I missing any configuration?

Comment: Put oozie sharelib under oozie user directory `/user/oozie/share/lib/...`

Comment: Hi @RamananR created a directory in HDFS as /user/oozie and placed the share/lib inside. Not working either. FYI : I have installed oozie under my user ID. All my Hadoop installation are available in my user ID

Comment: Hi @RamananR, this is my core-site.properties in hadoop <property>
<name>hadoop.proxyuser.mountain.hosts</name>
<value>*</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hadoop.proxyuser.mountain.groups</name>
<value>*</value>
</property> Oozie has been installed under user name 'mountain'

Answer (score 0):

Please Note that your user name is mountain that is the oozie-site.xml porperty

```
<property>
        <name>oozie.service.WorkflowAppService.system.libpath</name>
        <value>/user/${user.name}/share/lib</value>
        <description>
            System library path to use for workflow applications.
            This path is added to workflow application if their job properties sets
            the property 'oozie.use.system.libpath' to true.
        </description>
    </property>
```

States the Share lib jars are to be added in the above location as 
**/user/mountain/share/lib** . NOTE: **/user/${user.name}** is the username for the job oozie its should may vary according to the machine.
Make Sure that your share lib jar are to be placed under the **/user/mountain**. Extract the .gz(tar) file present in the oozie directory as **oozie-sharelib-4.1.0** 4.1.0 is version of oozie and upload the share folder in to the HDFS as mentioned in above path.

Answer (score 0):

In addition of the above reply, the time you run the below script from `$OOZIE_HOME/bin`,

```
oozie-setup.sh sharelib create -fs hdfs://localhost:9000
```

`oozie-setup.sh` pushes `oozie-sharelib-4.x.x.tar.gz` (located inside `$OOZIE_HOME` dir) untar contents (i.e. distcp, hcatalog, hive, hive2, mapreduce-streaming, oozie, pig, spark, sqoop and sharelib.properties) to your defined `/user/${user.name}/share/lib` (by default) `HDFS` location

but there is one point important to note here, first it creates a directory inside the `HDFS cluster` `share/lib/` (lib_ as of time format) like `lib_20171230083804`

and put the contents of lib inside that newly created directory, so the time user runs the oozie job, as configured oozie goes to the `oozie.service.WorkflowAppService.system.libpath` defined value but due to that above mentioned new kind of directory it didn't find any containing libraries inside and throw this kind of below error -

```
ACTION[0000000-171230085230873-oozie-arif-W@sqoop-node] Error starting action [sqoop-node]. ErrorType [FAILED], ErrorCode [It should never happen], Message [File /user/arif/share/lib does not exist]
```

So, here either you define the `oozie.service.WorkflowAppService.system.libpath` like `/user/${user.name}/share/lib/lib_20171230083804` or using `hadoop fs -mv` move the entire things inside the directory `lib_20171230083804` directly to the `share/lib/`, and thereafter -rerun the job again,

and can verify the sharelib list as below -

```
bin/oozie admin -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -shareliblist
```

and it will solve your issue, hope this will help someone, thanks.

Comment: and still if you are not able to see your shareliblist, then I assume that it will a kind of connectivity issue of your oozie console and database either with default derby, mysql, or something else it is using, also you can see oozie-error.log inside your $OOZIE_HOME/logs/ directory and the other logs file as well.